# If $z = 3+i$, find the values of n for which $Im(z^n)=0$

Tags: complex-numbers, pi

What I got is: 
$\sin(0.322n) = 0 $

Hence: 
$0.322n = \pi $
$n = 9.76$

and
$0.322n = 2\pi$
$n = 19.5$

and
$0.322n = 3pi $
$n = 29.27$
Hence set of n values is: 
$\pm[9.76,19.5,29.27....]$

This is what the Oxford book that I'm using has given as a solution:

[image: OXFORD SOLUTION]

Comment: I think you're supposed to find _integers_ $n$.

Comment: True but what makes my method invalid? How do I find the integers? Usually the angle comes something like (pi/2) according to which I'm able to find the integers.

Comment: your method is correct, but there are no integer solutions because pi/arctan(1/3) is irrational. You can however find real numbers $n$ for which this is true, as you have done

Comment: I wonder if you have misread the question. Might it be that $z=\sqrt 3 + i$?

Comment: Thank you for the information. The book from which I've taken this question, has done something completely different to get integer solutions which I do not understand at all. I'm just adding it to the question body.

Comment: @tomi I wish that was the case. Unfortunately I've written the question as it is in the book.

Comment: If $t=\arcsin{10^{-1/2}}$ then we need to check if $\pi/t$ is rational.... Can we?

Comment: You're right. The book is wrong. First, the value you get 0.322 is way better than their approximation that it's $\pi/{10}$. Then they solve for $\cos = 0$ rather than $\sin = 0$. Your answers are as good as you can get. My suspicion is that one person wrote the questions as $z=\sqrt 3+i$, which was mistyped by someone else (this happens!). Then someone else wrote the solution and made a pig's ear of it.

Comment: @tomi thanks a lot for the confirmation! I was having a really hard time with this question since the past month. Surprisingly Oxford has made a lot of mistakes in this book (Mathematics HL: Applications and Interpretation for the IB Diploma).

Comment: Publishers often rush to produce a book in time for a new academic year after a change of specification. As long as they sell it they don't mind a few errors. Sadly there is little or no time and money spent on proof-reading.

Comment: @tomi True. The current batch of IBDP 1 students are like lab rats. Many changes.

Comment: @PeterForeman correct. Thank you!

Comment: $(3+i)^5=-12+316i$ doesn't really look like a real number !? And the use of approximations is more than questionable.

Comment: @tomi Thankfully, lhf has made a silk purse out of the pig's ear. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $y_n = \operatorname{Im}((3+i)^n)$. Then $2y_n = (3+i)^n - (3-i)^n$ and so $y_{n+2}=6y_{n+1}-10y_n$ because $3\pm i$ are roots of $t^2=6t-10$. The first few values of $y_n$ are
$$
\begin{array}{c}
n & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4
\\
y_n & 0 &1 & 6 & 26 & 96
\end{array}
$$
It follows by induction from $y_{n+2}=6y_{n+1}-10y_n$  that $y_n \equiv 6 \bmod 10$ for $n\ge 2$. Thus, $y_n=0$ iff $n=0$.

So, the question is actually interesting, even if the solution given in the book is misguided and wrong.